# How to read .arff file in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Does anyone know how to read an .arff file in Google Colab?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff 

raw_data = loadarff('/content/Chronic_Kidney_Disease/chronic_kidney_disease_full.arff')
df_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data[0])
```

doesnt work.

```
    161         else:
    162             raise ValueError("%s value not in %s" % (str(data_str),
--> 163                                                      str(self.values)))
    164 
    165     def __str__(self):

ValueError:  yes value not in ('yes', 'no')
```

Comment: This question does not seem to be relevant to Google Colab. It's related to the `scipy` package that you're using. What is the exact error message? Use the Python stackoverflow tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved using the following code:

```
#Import the Libraries
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd

#Load the data using "arff.loadarff" then convert it to dataframe
data = arff.loadarff('spambase.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
```